# Lravel 5.4 : get products with favorite and display favorites product for each user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to get all products with favorite and display them as if user logged in and this products in favorite it will appear as favorite else he can add them to favorite.

here is my controller

```
$products = ( new Product )
            ->where( 'quantity', '>', 0 )
            ->with( 'favorite' )
            ->orderBy( 'price', $sort )->get();
```

now if I make `dd($product->favorite)` I get the favorite array like so

```
[{"id":1,"product_id":7,"user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-04-01 09:16:23","updated_at":"2018-04-01 09:16:23"}]
```

but if I try to select any of this array like `{{ $product->favorite->product_id }}`

I get

> Property [product_id] does not exist on this collection instance

How I display in blade

```
    @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                 <div class="thumbnail no-border no-padding">
                      <div class="media">
                      <a class="media-link" href="{!! URL::route('products.show', $product->id) !!}">
                      {!! Html::image('images/products/'.$product->image, $product->name) !!}
                      <span class="icon-view">
                      <strong><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></strong>
                      </span>
                      </a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="caption text-center">
                          <h4 class="caption-title">{!! $product->name !!}</h4>

                         <div class="price">
                         <ins>{!! $product->price !!}</ins>
                         {{--<del>$425.00</del>--}}
                         </div>
                         {{ $product->favorite->product_id }}
                      <div class="buttons">
                     @if(count($product->favorite) == 1)
                      <span class="btn btn-theme btn-theme-transparent">
                      <i class="fa fa-heart text-danger"></i>
                     </span>
                     @else
                     {!! Form::open(['route'=>'favorite.store', 'class'=>'favorite-products']) !!}
                     {!! Form::hidden('product_id', $product->id) !!}
                     @if ( Auth::guard( 'web' )->check() != 0 )
                     {!! Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::guard( 'web' )->user()->id) !!}
                     @endif
                     <button class="btn btn-theme btn-theme-transparent btn-wish-list">
                     <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                     </button>
                     @endif


                    {!! Form::close() !!}


                  {!! Form::open(['route'=>'add.to.cart', 'class'=>'btn product-shoppingcart-icon']) !!}
                 {!! Form::hidden('pro_id', $product->id) !!}
                 <button class="btn btn-theme btn-theme-transparent btn-icon-left">
                 <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>{{ trans('interface.addToCart') }}
                 </button>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
                <a class="btn btn-theme btn-theme-transparent btn-compare"
                href="#"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the current query is inefficient. As far as I understand, a product can be liked by many users. If you then load all favorites for each product, you will also load favorites that are not relevant for the current user. You should therefore only select relevant favorites:

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
    ->with(['favorite' => function ($hasMany) {
        $hasMany->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id);
    }])
    ->orderBy('price', $sort)
    ->get();
```

You will then end up with a collection of favorites on each product, although there may only be at most one favorite in the collection (because the current user can like a product only once, right?). So you want to access the thing in your view with:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    // ... your html here
    @if(count($product->favorite))
        <span class="btn btn-theme btn-theme-transparent">
            <i class="fa fa-heart text-danger"></i>
        </span>
    @endif
    // ... more html
@endforeach
```

Explanation: `$product->favorite` is a collection and `count()` will therefore give you the number of items. As there can be none or one favorite for the current user, we either receive `0` or `1` as result, which can also be seen as `false` and `true` respectively.

---

**Edit:** To avoid issues with not logged in users, you can use this query, which will simply not load the `favorite` relation then.

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
    ->orderBy('price', $sort)
    ->when(\Auth::check(), function ($query) {
        $query->with(['favorite' => function ($hasMany) {
            $hasMany->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id);
        }]);
    })
    ->when(\Auth::guest(), function ($query) {
        $query->with(['favorite' => function ($hasMany) {
            // will exclude all rows but flag the relation as loaded
            // and therefore add an empty collection as relation
            $hasMany->whereRaw('1 = 0');
        }]);
    })
    ->get();
```

Or in case someone doesn't like the weird database call that will always return zero rows, we can also set the relation manually:

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
    ->orderBy('price', $sort)
    ->when(\Auth::check(), function ($query) {
        $query->with(['favorite' => function ($hasMany) {
            $hasMany->where('user_id', \Auth::id());
        }]);
    })
    ->get();

if (\Auth::guest()) {
    $products->each(function ($product) {
        $product->setRelation('favorite', new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection());
    });
}
```

Comment: yes very good solution but there is one issue here what if the user id logged out `$hasMany->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)` this line indeed will give a problem because it's still checking for the user which is not there?

Comment: Good hint! See my edit in the answer regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach()` to loop through the `favorite` relation collections to show all `favorite` products.

```
 @foreach($product->favorite as $favorite)
       @if($favorite->product_id==$product->id)
            ///do what you want to do if check match
       @endif
 @endforeach
```

Comment: why you are showing `product_id` from relation array, you could simply get it from your product array, right?

Comment: Yes you are right what I want to accomplish in the end is to check if this `{{ $product->id }}`  == to `{{ $product->favorite->product_id }}` and the `user_id` == current session user_id so it's in this user favorite else he can added to the favorite

Comment: I didn't implement this check yet as I have problem getting the `$product->favorite->product_id`

Comment: @YousefAltaf see updated answer, it may give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

First make Favorite model and table name must be favorites or 
protected $table = 'favorites' write inside favorite model.

make relation in product model
 if product has many favorite

```
public function favorite(){
  return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class, 'product_id');
}
```

else product has one favorite

```
public function favorite(){
  return $this->hasOne(Favorite::class, 'product_id');
}
```

and in controller

```
$products = Product
             ->where( 'quantity', '>', 0 )
             ->orderBy( 'price', $sort )
             ->get();
```

and in view

```
@foreach($products as $product)

{{ $product->favorite->product_id }} //if product hasone relation with favorite

// if product hasmany relation in product
    @foreach($product->favorite as $favorite)
    {{ $favorite->product_id }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```